# Javascript bookmarklet with post command

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javascript bookmarklet which will use the HTTP POST method to send data to my php form from my browser.  I can't seem to get it working...can someone take a look and tell me why please?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params="v=66b12127";
xhr.open("POST", "http://google.com/index.php", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4) {
        window.alert("works");
    }
}
xhr.send(params);
```

In bookmark format:

```
javascript:var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();var params="v=66b12127";xhr.open("POST","http://google.com/index.php",true);xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4){window.alert("works");}}xhr.send(params);
```

Comment: Smells like a cross-domain issue to me.

Comment: I think you're right, Any solution you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That google page returns a 404.  However, assuming you just put that in there as an example, if you own the page your trying to post to, have it reply with an `Access-Control` header: http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-site-xmlhttprequest/

If you don't own the site, you can make a PHP page that accepts cross site requests and forwards them on to the other site.

Answer (score 7):

In most circumstances, you can't perform a POST request due to cross-domain restrictions (also called [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). However, if you are *only* interested in doing the request and not interested in reading the answer, there is a solution: With the bookmarklet, insert a `form` with the appropriate action attribute, then run the form's DOM object's `.submit()` function. Note that this will reload the whole page. If you want to avoid that, create an `iframe` as well and set the form's `target` attribute to its name. You can either choose to hide the iframe or—if you want the user to see the result—leave it visible.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is a cross-domain issue. With regular AJAX requests, you are limited to the domain the page is on. Modern browsers (FF3.5+, IE8+, Safari 4+, Chrome4+; Opera not at all) support something called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (see also [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) for a shorter and more practical introduction). As Telanor said, the server must respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for this to work (so no luck if it is not your own server), and things get much more complicated if you want cookie-based authentication. Also, while you can use the same API as with normal AJAX requests in most browsers, in IE8 you will need to create an [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object instead of an XMLHttpRequest. (There are frameworks to hide the ugly parts, of course; jQuery AJAX functions support it for example.)

If you need it to work in older browser, but don't care what the remote site replies, only that the POST call happens, create an invisible iframe and post there. If you need old browsers and need to return data, things get even more ugly; there are hacks like [this](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes), but it's a pain in the ass to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You may also write an userscript.

[GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) supports [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) which is similar to standard XMLHttpRequest, but allows to cross the same origin policy boundaries.

You should also be able to integrate it with bookmarklets if you will still need to.